# Non-convex classification with 2 layer MLP

Tags: neural-network, classification

Can 2-layer MLP (1 hidden layer and 1 output layer) classify the doughnut shape? or need 3 layer MLP?

[image]

Is there any important references to point this problem and prove how many layer needs to classify?

Comment: Yes it can. Check [the universial approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

A three layer neural network is no more powerful than a two layer one with a bigger hidden layer. The only reason to go deeper is that it is more efficient use of parameters to have multiple layers instead of a really big single hidden layer.